# Jenkins-Protractor Integration-Centos7

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, protractor, centos7

I am facing problem while integrating Jenkins with protractor script.

Steps:-
1. Created Freestyle project and i selected 'Execute Shell' build option and put protractor --version command.

2. When i build this simple job it says:- + protractor --version
   /tmp/jenkins5545881549145932714.sh: line 2: protractor: command not found
3. Same applies to npm --version, when i run this command got error :- npm: command not found.
4. But node --version works fine.

I am using centos7, and when i ran these commands on server command line, it works like charm.

Please Help!!

Comment: did you try executing protractor installation command with npm install protractor?
if you install with -g it will be available all time.

Comment: @YashJagdale:- Yes i have installed protractor globally, but on server via cmd it's working fine. Only while running with Jenkins it throws error.

Comment: That's because of Jenkins run process as Jenkins user. install globally with the Jenkins user worker node.

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar problem, devops fixed it by adding a statement to the command so in the result I had

```
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; cd ui-automation; protractor conf.js
```

still not completely understand what that does...

If that doesn't help, make sure your protractor and everything else are globally installed

Comment: thanks!! Yes protractor is installed globally but where i need to export this path?

Comment: this goes your shell script

Answer (score 0):

You can get the global package install path via `npm config get prefix`

```
NPM_PREFIX=`npm config get prefix`
export PATH=$NPM_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
protractor --version
```